# Nativescript - Lost databinding after app resume

Tags: nativescript

I have a View which is binded to a ViewModel (that inherits from Observable) with a TextField and a Switch.

When i change the values, all is binded perfectly and I can see my new values.

But if I go to the home screen and then, go back to the app, the values are erased.

The view is a basic form like a customer CRUD.

Here is the XML :

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
        loaded="loaded">
<!-- ... -->
  <TextView text="{{ valueA }}" />
<!-- ... -->
  <Slider value="{{ valueB }}" minValue="1950" maxValue="2016" />
</Page
```

Here is the code-behind :

```
let viewModel: ViewModel;
let page: Page;

export function loaded(args: EventData) {
    page = <Page>args.object;

    setTimeout(function() {
        viewModel = new ViewModel();
        page.bindingContext = viewModel;
    }, 0);
}
```

Do you have any idea why i loose my form data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, when you come back to the app, the `loaded` event is fired where you are constructing the view model. You should try constructing in a different page event (navigatedTo) or persist the data using the "application-settings" module. Then read the values from app-settings when you are constructing the observable view model. Hope this helps.

https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/application-settings/HOW-TO.html